# Установка Android studio

Tags: android, java, android-studio

Устанавливаю студию, но при запуске возникает ошибка:

> 'tools.jar' seems to be not in Android Studio classpath.
> Please ensure JAVA_HOME points to JDK rather than JRE.

В переменную JAVA_HOME я вписал путь C:\Program Files\Java\jre7
Я понимаю, что андроид требует установки JDK, но где его взять, на оф. сайте он даёт установить только JRE.

Comment: Установите для начала jdk. Гугл по первой же [ссылке его дает](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html). Правда, если Вы живете в России, то может [не дать скачать](http://habrahabr.ru/post/232633/).

Answer (score 0):

Скачать JDK можно вот [отсюда](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

JRE - это средства для выполнения программ написанных на Java.
JDK - это средства для разработки на Java и выполнения программ написанных на Java.
JDK можно скачать [тут](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html).